# Method App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::manage_category does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I am a new learner of laravel. I face problem while running my code.  Method App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController::manage_category does not exist.

Here is my code:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/category');
    }
    
    public function manage_category()
    {
        
        return view('admin/manage_category');
    }
}
```

Here is my web route code:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AdminController;
use App\Http\Controllers\CategoryController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('admin',[AdminController::class,'index']);
Route::post('admin/auth',[AdminController::class,'auth'])->name('admin.auth');  

Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin_auth'],function(){
 
        Route::get('admin/dashboard',[AdminController::class,'dashboard']);
        Route::get('admin/category',[CategoryController::class,'index']);
        Route::get('admin/manage_category',[CategoryController::class,'manage_category']);
});
```

Comment: Do you have a `public function manage_category()` in your `CategoryController.php` file? There is literally nothing else we can do to help unless you show the code causing this error...

Comment: Yes I have    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('admin/category');
    }
 
  function manage_category()
 {
  
  return view('admin/manage_category');
 }

}

Comment: No, you do not. You have `function manage_category()`, not `public function manage_category()`. There's your error. Also, next time, please edit your question; don't post code in comments when you can edit your question and format it better. (I did this for you this time, but next time it's up to you :))

Comment: Dear Tim Lewis i do it to public function but result is same, still showing same error.

Comment: @TimLewis Default method visibility is `public` (though it's obviously very bad practice to omit it).

Comment: @Jeto Ah, good to know. I feel like I've run into that issue before when omitting `public`, but maybe not. @ahmadbhatti, next question, where/how are you calling this `manage_category` function? What code is throwing this error?

Comment: @Tim Lewis i am calling it from my route/web

Comment: Once again, **please post the code you're using**.

Comment: @jeto no no is exit in App/Http/Controllers

Comment: @TimLewis code is:<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('admin',[AdminController::class,'index']);
Route::post('admin/auth',[AdminController::class,'auth'])->name('admin.auth'); 

Route::group(['middleware'=>'admin_auth'],function(){
 
        Route::get('admin/dashboard',[AdminController::class,'dashboard']);
        Route::get('admin/category',[CategoryController::class,'index']);
     Route::get('admin/manage_category',[CategoryController::class,'manage_category']);
});

Comment: Why did you post the code in the comments when I specifically told you to **edit your question and post the code there?**

Comment: @Tim Lewis i am new here so kindly please bear me.I am posting it in my question

Comment: It's fine to be new here, we all were at one point, but please try to follow the instructions. We're trying to help, but you're making it more difficult than it needs to be 

Comment: Your code should work fine now. Did you restart your server and/or clear your routing cache? If you're using `php artisan serve`, kill that process and run it again. If you're doing route caching, run this: `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @Tim Lewis it working now i cleared routing caching and run it again . God bless you. Thank you for mentoring me.

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad your code looks fine try below to clear the cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan view:clear
```